# Invalidate and restart for a single project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, caching, ide

I would like to invalidate caches and restart only for a single project, with multiple opened. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Seems not possible](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250049/Invalidate-cache-and-restart-for-a-single-project):

> This is not possible with the current architecture; caches are not
> per-project (for example, if you have a library that is used in
> multiple projects, it will be indexed only once and those indices will
> be used by all projects)